# Is there an equivalent ip command parameter to the ifup "--force" argument?

Tags: networking, ip, ifconfig

As `ipconfig` is depricated, I am looking at the `ip` command.

As `ip` can up/down interfaces, I am also looking to change `ifup` etc.

But I do not see an `ip` equivilent to the likes of:

`ifup --force wlan0`

Or is "`--force`" not needed, or not recommended now?

Comment: I am looking at : [https://github.com/dweeber/WiFi_Check](https://github.com/dweeber/WiFi_Check).  That uses it,  I am changing that in a couple of areas, and wanted to update the if* commands in there, but was not sure how much difference the ```--force``` arg made?

Comment: The code mentioned above has ```--force``` on the ```ifup``` command.  I would have thought it made more sense on the ```ifdown``` though...?

Comment: I see that [http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip-link.8.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip-link.8.html) has ```-force``` that seems to be accepted when running ```ip -force link set enp3s0 down```.  But is that doing anything useful?